# Ubuntu cannot find "gems" package after installing Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I was following this tutorial (http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html) of installing ruby with RVM on Xubuntu 14.04 running on virtual box. I completed this step with success:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

However afterward I tried to run `gem -v` and got this output:

> > The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages:
> >
> > - ruby
> > - rubygems
> >
> > Try: sudo apt-get install

I also tried to reinstall Ruby with the argument `--autolibs=enable` but it did not change the outcome.

EDIT:

Running `rvm list` output:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: what is the output of `rvm list`?

Comment: When installing RVM, following the directions on http://rvm.io/rvm/install, not on other sites. The folks who wrote RVM know better than anyone else how to install it. There are troubleshooting tips on that page, along with all the steps to correctly install it, so read through it and see what you find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `~/.bashrc` file paste this line at the bottom:

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Then restart your terminal session, and you should be able to `gem install` via RVM.

Comment: That line goes in ~/.bash_profile. From the documentation: `echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile`. Following restarting the shell, it's necessary to run `rvm use 2.1.5 --default` otherwise RVM won't know which Ruby to use and will default to the system.

Comment: It can go in either.  `.bash_profile` is loaded when user logs in.  While `.bashrc` is loaded every terminal window

Comment: I understand how it works. I am relaying how the authors of RVM recommend, and expect, it to be set up.

Comment: You can also check "Run command as a login shell" in the terminal's profile preferences (eg. Ubuntu) in order for the default installation of rvm to use ~/.bash_profile settings from rvm.

Comment: For those in the same situation I was: Adding the command in `~/.bashrc` is the only place that works for me. Adding the command in`~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.profile` didn't work even after the re-logged.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `~/.bash_profile` file.
If you see a line like:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

then you just need to restart the machine (or log out and log in back).
Otherwise follow the Tin Man's instructions above, log out and log in again (or restart the machine).

Comment: In my bash_profile file has the exact same line as you posted here, but even restarting my session it didn't work. I can check through rvm that ruby is installed.